# Fastest DataFrame or Dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset, `30 rows and 6 columns`. Every 0.5 sec, 2 new rows pop up and I have to update my DataFrame or Dictionary according to these 2 rows. I will have a maximum of 40 rows * 6 columns in my dataset. What is the best/fastest tool, a DataFrame or a dictionary to solve this problem? Thank you

here is my structure:

```
0     1  140.97   1.86    1
1     1  141.00   2.88    1
2     1  141.16   3.23    1
3     1  141.24   0.33    1
4     1  141.25   2.24    1
5     1  141.64   1.30    1
6     1  141.81   1.42    1
7     1  141.82   1.91    1
8     1  142.07   1.36    1
9     1  142.08   2.32    1
10    1  142.16   1.98    1
11    1  142.19   0.45    1
12    1  142.42   2.39    1
13    1  142.62   2.08    1
14    1  142.64   3.33    1
15    1  142.73   1.45    1
16    1  142.83   2.72    1
17    1  142.99   1.84    1
18    1  143.31   0.68    1
19    1  143.34   2.54    1
20    1  143.46   2.92    1
21    1  143.54   1.54    1
22    1  143.74   2.39    1
23    1  143.82   2.01    1
24    1  220.00  15.50    1
25    0  140.26   1.44    1
26    0  140.09   2.27    1
27    0  139.71   1.98    1
28    0  139.22   0.11    1
29    0  138.72   2.90    1
30    0  138.20   3.29    1
31    0  129.00   0.01    1
```

Comment: `DataFrame`  will be better

Comment: On a dataset of 40 rows and 6 columns, the difference will not be noticeable.

Comment: The answer to your question is heavily dependent on the type of data you're working with, and how large each data point actually is. Sure, you have some limited number of rows and columns, but how big are the data points themselves? If you use a dictionary, it could be costly to hash a large string, for example. All this is to say, we need more context. Please show us your data and associated code so that we can frame our answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084338/pandas-dataframe-performance)