# How do I efficiently update a field within a dataframe based on boolean operators on 4 other fields in the record?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I am analysing and summarising a dataset ("the **Report**") as a Python pandas dataframe. The table indicates the result of a matching process between 4 different datasets ("the **Inputs**") that should all match on the same key.

In the **Report** there is a field for each of the **Inputs** with a counter of the number of matches (>=0) to the base dataset. I want to update a field in the Report to indicate how many of the datasets match the base data ("*matchCounter*"), so for any number of successful matches (i.e. >0), the *matchCounter* should increment with 1, with a maximum of 4 (i.e. all four datasets match the base data).

I developed the process in Jupyter notebooks on a small dataset of around 100'000 records, and while I was successful in updating the *matchCounter* fields, I suspect it's taking longer than it should. The full dataset is 10'000'000 records, and according to my rough calculations that would take more than 8 hours to complete with my current code (on what I think is a pretty simple operation).

I've read up a bit on improving the performance of a dataframe ([Pandas DataFrame performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084338/pandas-dataframe-performance)), but since I'm iterating over the rows sequentially and the if-statements are tested on items in the row and not the dataframe, I don't know whether this applies.

Here is a summarised version of the code. The first for loop is the one causing the bottleneck:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(fileIn, header=0)

df['match_count']= 0
df['exclude']= False

# This for loop takes 300+ seconds to execute 100'000 times     
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matchCounter = 0
    if row['in_deeds'] > 0:
        matchCounter += 1
    if row['in_valuation'] > 0:
        matchCounter += 1
    if row['in_property'] > 0:
        matchCounter += 1
    if row['in_sg'] > 0:
        matchCounter += 1
    df.loc[index,'match_count'] = matchCounter

# This for loop takes only 11.75 seconds
i=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if "EXCL" in row['stat_deeds'].upper():
        i=i+1
        df.loc[index,'exclude']=True
    elif "EXCL" in row['stat_valuation'].upper():
        i=i+1
        df.loc[index,'exclude']=True
    elif "EXCL" in row['stat_property'].upper():
        i=i+1
        df.loc[index,'exclude']=True
    elif "EXCL" in row['stat_sg'].upper():
        i=i+1
        df.loc[index,'exclude']=True

df = df.query('exclude == False')
```

This is my first time working with Pandas, and I am also very much a beginner at Python, so I assume I am making a stupid mistake. But I am also not sure whether my expectation is wrong, and that this is just the performance that I should expect. Is there a better way? Even if someone could just point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update after OP comment:

```
df['match_count']=(df[['in_deeds','in_valuation','in_property','in_sg']]>0).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```

The following will also provide the total amount of matches at each point (each row) by taking the cumulative sum of the match counts.

```
df['match_count']=(df[['in_deeds','in_valuation','in_property','in_sg']]>0).astype(int).sum(axis=1).cumsum()
```

**Piece by piece**:

We first check (for each row) if the value in the specified columns is bigger than zero. This return a boolean `True` or `False`, which we transform in integer `.astype(int)`

```
df[['in_deeds','in_valuation','in_property','in_sg']]>0).astype(int)
```

We then sum this values for each row `.sum(axis=1)`.
This will return a single column where on each row we know how many conditions (`>0`) were satisfied.

We finally take the cumulative sum across the rows to obtain the total number (at each row) of matches.

We finally create a new column `df['match_count']=` in the original dataframe `df` and assign the result to that column.

Comment: Thanks, Gio, I cannot believe how simple and efficient the solution is. The only change I had to make was to remove `.cumsum()`, as I actually wanted the total match per record and not the cumulative count over all the records (sorry if my question was unclear).

Comment: You can (and should) update my answer then. It's always useful to have the solution clear for the next user that will encounter the same problem

Comment: Okay great, thanks Gio - I wasn't sure about that, I'll remember in future.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues in the past with iterating over dataframes - [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) seems like the right choice at first glance due to the ease of use, but the convenience comes at a price. Here's [a helpful blog](https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc) that outlines methods in pandas to iterate more efficiently.

The upshot is - don't use `iterrows`. In general, the rows of the dataframe can be accessed by using the index as an iterator and then using `df.loc` or `df.iloc` like so:

```
for i in df.index:
  print(df.loc[i, :])
```

### Using `df.apply`

The `apply` method allows you to apply a user-defined function to all column or rows of a dataframe. While the use here can be somewhat unintuitive, it is by far the fastest:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def counter(row):

    if np.any(row[row > 0]):
        return np.sum(row[row > 0])
    else:
        return 0

N = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 2, N),
                   'B': np.random.randint(0, 2, N),
                   'C': np.random.randint(0, 2, N),
                   'D': np.random.randint(0, 2, N)})

df['match-count'] = df.apply(counter, axis=1, raw=True)
```

Here, the function will check each *row* of the dataframe (specified by `axis=1`); `np.any` returns `True` if the boolean selection `row[row > 0]` is not empty, at which point the boolean selection is reduced with `np.sum` to get the final count. We the `raw` keyword argument as `True` so that the raw `numpy` array is passed, which should be used in reduction operations (like sum) for performance increases (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

This takes about 1.2 seconds to run on my machine.

## Edit

Gio's answer shows a principle that I think is good practice when using pandas - if methods exist (e.g `sum`, `cumsum`) that can operate on dataframes directly, try and utilise those, as they will always be quicker.

Where methods like this don't exist, `df.apply` can be useful if specifying more complicated operations to apply - just a tip for the future!

## Edit II

The example with apply above assumes that all of the columns within the dataframe are used in the boolean selection. If only specific columns have numeric values that need to be used for the counter, use Gio's suggestion within the `counter` method:

```
def counter(row):

    selection = row[['in_deeds', 'in_valuation', 'in_property', 'in_sg']] > 0

    if np.any(selection):
        return np.sum(selection)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that [blog post](https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc) really helped me understand a few things much better!

Comment: Thanks, Dagorodir. I've also been trying out your df.apply() solution, but I keep getting an error and can't get around it. The error is: `TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0')`. Can it be that it is trying to compare the column heading to 0?

Comment: It might be that you have other columns than those you specified in the question which are of string type? the function in apply will perform boolean selection based on all the columns of the particular row its looking at, so if there are strings they won't be able to be compared in `row > 0`. You could, however, use the line that Gio included in his answer within the `np.any()` and `np.sum()` methods - see most recent edit