# Making a Python Program faster

Tags: python, excel, pandas, performance

Last night i was developing a python code that compares a Excel (4 columns, 30 thousand lines) to another Excel (4 columns, 30 thousand lines), generating another Excel with the differences found. The structure is very similar to the code following this text, firstly, it finds an specific product in the other excel, and them compares their attributes. It works really well, the problem is: it takes 80 hours to run this code, and i need to run in no longer than 2. This example below is a simple version of the real code, the real one deals with XLSX with 30 thousand rows and more than 90 columns. How can i make it quicker?

```
#imports

from datetime import date

import pandas as pd

import xlsxwriter

#reading XLS's

tabelac = pd.read_excel('TESTE.xlsx', 'Dados')
tabelae = pd.read_excel('TESTE2.xlsx', 'Dados')

#Excluding Nan Values

print(len(tabelac))

for i in range(len(tabelac)):

  produto = tabelac.loc[i,'Produto']
  if pd.isna(produto):
    tabelac.loc[i,'Produto'] = ''

  preco = tabelac.loc[i,'Preço']
  if pd.isna(preco):
    tabelac.loc[i,'Preço'] = ''

  tipo = tabelac.loc[i,'Tipo']
  if pd.isna(tipo):
    tabelac.loc[i,'Tipo'] = ''
    
  Q_vendas = tabelac.loc[i,'Q_vendas']
  if pd.isna(Q_vendas):
    tabelac.loc[i,'Q_vendas'] = ''

for i in range(len(tabelae)):

  produto = tabelae.loc[i,'Produto']
  if pd.isna(produto):
    tabelae.loc[i,'Produto'] = ''

  preco = tabelae.loc[i,'Preço']
  if pd.isna(preco):
    tabelae.loc[i,'Preço'] = ''

  tipo = tabelae.loc[i,'Tipo']
  if pd.isna(tipo):
    tabelae.loc[i,'Tipo'] = ''
    
  Q_vendas = tabelae.loc[i,'Q_vendas']
  if pd.isna(Q_vendas):
    tabelae.loc[i,'Q_vendas'] = ''

#printing XLS's

print(tabelac)
print()
print('--------------------------')
print()
print(tabelae)

#declaring error list

erros = []

#evaluating errors

for i in range(len(tabelac)):
  
  for e in range(len(tabelae)):
    
    if tabelac.loc[i,'Produto'] == tabelae.loc[e,'Produto']:
      
      if tabelac.loc[i,'Preço'] != tabelae.loc[e,'Preço']:
        erros.append(f'Divergência no Preço do produto {tabelac.loc[i,"Produto"]}')
        
      if tabelac.loc[i,'Tipo'] != tabelae.loc[e,'Tipo']:
        erros.append(f'Divergência Tipo do produto {tabelac.loc[i,"Produto"]}')
        
      if tabelac.loc[i,'Q_vendas'] != tabelae.loc[e,'Q_vendas']:
        erros.append(f'Divergência preço do produto {tabelac.loc[i,"Produto"]}')

#evaluating missing products

for i in range(len(tabelac)):
  for e in range(len(tabelae)):
    if tabelac.loc[i,'Produto'] == tabelae.loc[e,'Produto']:
      break
    if tabelac.loc[i,'Produto'] != tabelae.loc[e,'Produto'] and (e+1) == len(tabelae):
      erros.append(f'O produto {tabelac.loc[i,"Produto"]} não foi encontrado em ambas as tabelas')

for i in range(len(tabelae)):
  for e in range(len(tabelac)):
    if tabelae.loc[i,'Produto'] == tabelac.loc[e,'Produto']:
      break
    if tabelae.loc[i,'Produto'] != tabelac.loc[e,'Produto'] and (e+1) == len(tabelac):
      erros.append(f'O produto {tabelae.loc[i,"Produto"]} não foi encontrado em ambas as tabelas')
      
#printing results to compare with XLSX

for i in range(len(erros)):
  print()
  print(erros[i])

#generating the XLS's to exhibit values obtained
 
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Results.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 3
column = 0

data_atual = date.today()

data_em_texto = '{}/{}/{}'.format(data_atual.day, data_atual.month,data_atual.year)

worksheet.write(0, 0, f'XLS generated in {data_em_texto}')

worksheet.write(1, 0, '')

worksheet.write(2, 0, 'Errors Found')


for item in erros:
 
    # write operation perform
  
    worksheet.write(row, column, item)
 
    # incrementing the value of row by one 
  
    row += 1
     
workbook.close()
```

If I were supposed to compare the first XLSX with 4 lists(Products, Type, Price, Sales Amount), is there a better method to perform this task?

Comment: are you able to identify the slowest part of the code? Is the actual loading of the 2 excel files or the elaboration? From your code, everytime you call `len()` function it have to calculate it which could be heavy if the file is big

Comment: This might be duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084338/pandas-dataframe-performance

I'd review the answers in that question. Focus on modularizing your code so that you can time performance easier. And there's a lot of information on the internet about optimizing performance of pandas / dataframe processing. As asked this question might belong here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, if this data is fairly static / grows daily, you may just run it on the new rows that get added.

Comment: I wouldn't call an excel with 30k rows "a very huge". A very huge excel could have a million rows.

Comment: I think you should use one of the answers below and use pandas to perform the operations, if you need to speed it up even more, please have a look at how to [enhance performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html) of pandas using Numba or Cython.

Answer (score 0):

4x30k rows is a small file.

As pointed multiple times in StackOverflow, **do not loop over rows, pandas is prepared to operate matrix-wise**.
In your case you not only you have row iteration but **nested for** which builds to N² time.

For instance, `.fillna` is orders of magnitude faster than `for`+`isna`

You have multiple ways to proceed, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `on='Produto'` is likely a good candidate:

- `how='outer'` Will create a 30x4..8 columns. Columns will have `_x` on the first file, `_y` on the second one

From there, you can see if `_x` and `_y` have data and extract the if product is in A, in B, or in both

**Edit: proof of concept example** (not tested)

```
tabelac = pd.read_excel('TESTE.xlsx', 'Dados')
tabelae = pd.read_excel('TESTE2.xlsx', 'Dados')

merged = tabelac.merge(tabelae, how='outer', left_on='Produto', right_on='Produto')

wrong_price = merged['Preço_x']!=merged['Preço_y']
wrong_type =  merged['Tipo_x']!=merged['Tipo_y']

# (...and so on)

print(f"Products with wrong price: {merged[wrong_price]}")

# To dump the full table at once:
merged[wrong_price].to_excel('items_with_wrong_price.xlsx')
```