# Extracting elements from a long list of dictionaries efficiently

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, vectorization

I have a (long) list of dictionaries, but for the sake of this example I represent them as

```
d = [{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'a':3}]
```

I need to extract the same element from these dictionaryes, i.e.,

```
[i['a'] for i in d]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python? List comprehensions and for-loops work well, but are not known to be very efficient. Can the process be vectorized somehow?

---

Additional details: The dictionaries have multiple keys, but it is the same one that I need to extract. All the dictionaries have the same keys.

Comment: reorganize your data once and for all with a dictionary of lists, for instance `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: _"Can the process be vectorized somehow"_: Are you willing to use an external library that will provide this vectorization? If yes, check out [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: The dictionary is a very sparse data structure per se. So since you're working with it from the start, it won't become any faster. Reorganize your data for better performance.

Comment: If you proceed working with a  list of dictionaries, looping is straightforward (and inevitable) for you. For vectorization you'd need to keep data in another data structure

Comment: Your example is likely too minimal. Do you have other keys? Do you need to repeat the process? Do you always have the same keys in all dictionaries? Jean-François' suggestion is probably the most reasonable.

Comment: Do you actually need the result as a *list*?

Comment: *list comprehensions .... but are not known to be very efficient.*  If you stay in "mono-processing" Python, comprehensions are generally one of the more efficient constructs - and have apparently become more so in 3.12 - so this statement is quite misleading.  Of course, multi-processing, Pandas, Polars and sundry can save the day on large data volumes, when appropriate, but vanilla Python does quite well with comprehensions, more so than for-loops for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas`. You have to pay the upfront costs of import and creating a data frame. But the subsequent operations are vectorized and efficient:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'a':1, 'b':11}, {'a':2, 'b':12}, {'a':3, 'b':13}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df['a'])
print(list(df['a']))
```

Prints:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Benchmarking:**

The results is that `pandas` data frame is slightly faster than the list of dictionaries for medium-size datasets, not including the cost of creating the data frame.

The benchmarking code is based on the answer by *JL Peyret*.
Note that, unlike in that answer, I place data frame initialization (not just `import pandas`) **outside** the benchmarking loop. I benchmark simply access to the elements of the data structure. The data structure also has more rows (1 million). I assume that this scenario is an alternative realistic scenario for medium-size datasets.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import timeit

def pandas_dict(datain):
    return list(df["a"])

def list_comp(datain):
    return [v["a"] for v in datain]

nrows = 1000000

rand = list(range(nrows))
random.shuffle(rand)

data = [{"a":rand[i], "b":rand[i]} for i in range(nrows)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

results = []

for totest in [list_comp, pandas_dict]:
    print(totest.__name__)
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt='totest(data)', number=100, globals=globals()))
    res = totest(data)
    results.append(res)
    print(f"{res[0:10]=}, {len(res)=}")
```

Results:

```
             a       b
0       847669  847669
1       777701  777701
2       446229  446229
3       984577  984577
4       813383  813383
...        ...     ...
999995  636811  636811
999996  413271  413271
999997  346275  346275
999998  414864  414864
999999  381832  381832

[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
list_comp
4.460098167066462
res[0:10]=[847669, 777701, 446229, 984577, 813383, 705699, 7830, 466819, 485673, 400344], len(res)=1000000
pandas_dict
4.201689457986504
res[0:10]=[847669, 777701, 446229, 984577, 813383, 705699, 7830, 466819, 485673, 400344], len(res)=1000000
```

**See also:**

[Pandas DataFrame performance compared to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084742/967621)

Comment: I’m actually surprised that the pandas data access was *barely* faster than the list comp.  Pandas 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I have `pandas-1.5.2-py3.11` installed by `conda`, running on MacBook Pro Apple M1 Max, Sonoma 14.0.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I missed something, list comprehension is fastest, then polars, then pandas.

```
import timeit

import polars as pl
import pandas as pd


def polars_dict(datain):
    df = pl.from_dicts(datain)
    return df.to_series(0).to_list()

def pandas_dict(datain):
    df = pd.DataFrame(datain)
    return list(df["a"])

def list_comp(datain):
    return [v["a"] for v in datain]

data = [{"a":1,"b":2}] * 10000

results = []

for totest in [list_comp, polars_dict, pandas_dict]:

    print(totest.__name__)
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt='totest(data)',number=10,globals=globals()))
    res = totest(data)
    results.append(res)
    print(f"{res[0:50]=}, {len(res)=}")

print(results[0] == results[1] == results[2])
```

##### output:

```
list_comp
0.003527630993630737
res[0:50]=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], len(res)=10000
polars_dict
0.02488957904279232
res[0:50]=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], len(res)=10000
pandas_dict
0.06578049197560176
res[0:50]=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], len(res)=10000
True
```

Bottom line:  **by itself, without anything else to do**, neither pandas not polars improve anything.  You can vary the data length to make it bigger, but that didn't change things all that much.

p.s. This is on 3.11. 3.12 has optimized away the previously generated function that’s behind the scene to iterate items in a list comp and now unwinds it inline.  That should do away w function call overhead.

Comment: Another candidate, which I suspected *could* be faster: `[*map(operator.itemgetter("a"), datain)]`. But it's slightly slower than the list comp for me (in Python 3.11.4). It was the fastest of a few `map` solutions that I tried, so now I don't see anything left that could beat the list comp (except a solution written in C to do exactly this job).

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would do it directly if I did not have a need for Pandas otherwise:

```
LoD = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':18}, {'a':3}, {'b':3}, {'c':3}, {'b':2}]

di={}

for d in LoD:
    for k,v in d.items():
        di.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

>>> di
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 2], 'c': [18, 3]}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about use generator:

```py
from typing import Any, Generator


def iter_one_key(ds: list[dict[str, Any]], key: str) -> Generator:
    for i in range(len(ds)):
        yield ds[i][key]


def main():
    d = [{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}, {"a": 3}]
    for v in iter_one_key(d, "a"):
        print(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: as JL say, this does not make it more efficient. It just save memory.

Comment: I have an extremely hard time believing this will make things any more efficient given that it uses substantially the same approach, loop - then dict access - just in a more convoluted manner.   -1 for complexity without any timings to support time improvements with needless typing to boot